# background image not fits all screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fit my background image to any screen, when my open in laptop its fine but in desktop it loose some part of image. I tried the CSS but is there anything in the CSS i miss?

But the datalist and button comes in the exact center in all screen including mobile but not my background image. Please help..

```js
$('#btn').click(function() { // The `$` reference here is a jQuery syntax. So we are loading jquery right before this script tag
  var textval = $('#textcat').val();
  window.location = "1stlink.php?variable=" + encodeURIComponent(textval);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.place {
  height: 30px;
}

.place[placeholder] {
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* CSS */

.btnExample {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #228B22;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
}

.btnExample:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #008000;
}

.img-box {
  /*position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;*/
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('bgimage101.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#category {
  width: 500px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="text-center align-middle">
        <input list="category" name="category" id="textcat" class="place" placeholder="Enter your area.." style="width: 400px !important">
        <datalist id="category">
        <option id="www.google.com" value="fruits" />
        <option id="www.fb.com" value="animals" />
        <option id="www.ymail.com" value="vechiles" />
        <option id="www.msn.com" value="ornaments" />
      </datalist>
        <input class="btnExample" id="btn" type="button" value="Search">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your fixed container class

```
.container{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-image: url('bgimage101.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      border: 1px solid red;
        }
    or
    
    .container{
      background-image: url('bgimage101.jpg');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-size:contain;
      background-position:center;
      }
```

```js
$('#btn').click(function() { // The `$` reference here is a jQuery syntax. So we are loading jquery right before this script tag
  var textval = $('#textcat').val();
  window.location = "1stlink.php?variable=" + encodeURIComponent(textval);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.place {
  height: 30px;
}

.place[placeholder] {
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* CSS */

.btnExample {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #228B22;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
}

.btnExample:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #008000;
}

.img-box {
  /*position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;*/
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-image: url('bgimage101.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      border: 1px solid red;
        }

#category {
  width: 500px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="text-center align-middle">
        <input list="category" name="category" id="textcat" class="place" placeholder="Enter your area.." style="width: 400px !important">
        <datalist id="category">
        <option id="www.google.com" value="fruits" />
        <option id="www.fb.com" value="animals" />
        <option id="www.ymail.com" value="vechiles" />
        <option id="www.msn.com" value="ornaments" />
      </datalist>
        <input class="btnExample" id="btn" type="button" value="Search">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
.container{
background-image: url("Your image address");
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.container {
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}
```

When you use `background-size: cover;` the background image scales to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area.

Comment: but athi the image comes entirely but the top and bottom of the page is filled with blank space. is there anything i should do  on selecting the image of appropriate size?

Comment: Then you can use background-size: cover; but the whole image might not be in view. You can select an image of appropriate size.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```css
.container{
    background-image: url(../images/image.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 100vh; //with this you'll not lose image
}
```